# Getting Client IP Address UC Browser and Opera Mini

Tags: php, opera-mini, uc-browser

I want to get the client's IP address with PHP. It is giving the client IP address except in UC Browser and Opera Mini.

Can anyone help me to get the IP address from these two browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Opera Mini you can use the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header as described here: https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-request-headers/